# Passing over to something

Tags: word-usage

Proceeding with, say, an agenda item or a new activity, we might say:

> Let's move on the the next item/activity.
>
> Let's get to the next item/activity.

Recently I heard *Let's pass over to the activity*. As far as I understand, it's not the phrasal verb *pass over* which is used but the verb *pass* + *over to* something. Does it make sense to you? Can *pass* be used like this?

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase

> **pass over**

does have the meaning to *bypass something*, just as a road can have a **pass over** (or *overpass*)

[image: a bridge over a highway]

Often the phrase

> **skip over**

gets used to express this meaning.

> If you are already familiar with the material, you may **skip over** the introductory chapter.

During meals at a large gathering, you might say

> **pass over** the potatoes

which has a completely different meaning, *pass the bowl of potatoes over to me*.